# How to make custom dictionary for password recovery

Tags: windows-vista, password-recovery, keepass

I forgot my password to KeePass, but I know almost all of the letters/numbers and the order they go in.

I usually have a main password then add some stuff before and after that. Everything I try I get invalid/wrong key error.

I also enabled *use master password* and *key file* (on my flash drive).

Is there a word or password generator that will do every combo of my usual passwords?

Example of the passwords would be:

- pswd (core)
- wordpswd
- "wordpswd"
- wordpswd12
- pswds12
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using bash shell expansion,

echo {m,M}{y,Y}pass{_,__}

etc.

whack that in a for loop.

edit, just seen your windows-vista tag. sorry, that's outside my area of fun. - try a linux live cd and get the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) as described in [Cracking a Keepass database](https://github.com/patecm/cracking_keepass).